# Custom directory enumeration using System.IO.Enumeration in .NET Core

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-core

The author of [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jeremykuhne/custom-directory-enumeration-in-net-core-2-1) mentioned there is a newer API for quicker method of file and directory enumeration.  But though the article seems to refer to examples, they are not present and I can't find any examples elsewhere on Google that use the new methods mentioned?

Does anyone have some example code that could enumerate a given folder and all sub-folders / files to return information such as size and last accessed etc?

Answer (score 9):

I can see why you found it difficult to figure this out - there isn't much information around, and so I ended up digging around the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Enumeration/FileSystemEnumerableFactory.cs) to figure things out. For the following examples, I'm using this directory structure:

```
D:\Root\
|- Child\
|  |- Grandchild\
|  |  |- Grandchild.jpg
|  |  |- Grandchild.txt
|  |- Child.html
|  |- Child.txt
|- Root.txt
```

and importing the following namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Enumeration;
```

#### Example 1: Listing all files and subdirectories, recursively

```
var enumeration = new FileSystemEnumerable<FileSystemInfo>(
    @"D:\Root",
    // What's returned here has to match the generic type
    // passed in when creating the FileSystemEnumerable.
    // As DirectoryInfo inherits from FileSystemInfo, we
    // can use FileSystemInfo for both directories and files.
    (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => entry.ToFileSystemInfo(),
    // Should be self-explanatory.
    new EnumerationOptions() { RecurseSubdirectories = true })
{
    // We want to include everything: all directories and files.
    ShouldIncludePredicate = (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => true
};
```

As `FileSystemEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, for our example it's a case of iterating over a collection of `FileSystemInfo` - there's nothing special here:

```
foreach (var item in enumeration)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.FullName} - {item.LastAccessTime}");
}
```

which prints:

```
D:\Root\Child - 03/10/2020 18:34:16
D:\Root\Root.txt - 03/10/2020 17:39:54
D:\Root\Child\Child.html - 03/10/2020 18:27:20
D:\Root\Child\Child.txt - 03/10/2020 17:40:15
D:\Root\Child\Grandchild - 03/10/2020 18:44:36
D:\Root\Child\Grandchild\Grandchild.jpg - 03/10/2020 18:44:28
D:\Root\Child\Grandchild\Grandchild.txt - 03/10/2020 17:40:10
```

You'll notice a couple of things:

1. Even when recursing, from the caller's perspective, it's a flat structure
2. It appears results are ordered first by subdirectories in alphabetical order, and then by filenames in alphabetical order

#### Example 2: Listing all subdirectories, recursively

```
// We're returning strings this time.
var enumeration = new FileSystemEnumerable<string>(
    @"D:\Root",
    // Returns the full path to the directory.
    (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => entry.ToFullPath(),
    new EnumerationOptions() { RecurseSubdirectories = true })
{
    // Only include directories in the result set.
    ShouldIncludePredicate = (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => entry.IsDirectory
};
```

Running this:

```
foreach (var item in enumeration)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

prints:

```
D:\Root\Child
D:\Root\Child\Grandchild
```

#### Example 3: Filtering files by extension

```
var extensions = new List<string> { ".html", ".jpg" };

// Back to using FileSystemInfo.
var enumeration = new FileSystemEnumerable<FileSystemInfo>(
    @"D:\Root",
    (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => entry.ToFileSystemInfo(),
    new EnumerationOptions() { RecurseSubdirectories = true })
{
    ShouldIncludePredicate = (ref FileSystemEntry entry) =>
    {
        // Skip directories.
        if (entry.IsDirectory) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        foreach (string extension in extensions)
        {
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(entry.FileName);
            if (fileExtension.EndsWith(extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Include the file if it matches one of our extensions.
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Doesn't match, so exclude it.
        return false;
    }
};
```

Running this:

```
foreach (var item in enumeration)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.FullName);
}
```

prints:

```
D:\Root\Child\Child.html
D:\Root\Child\Grandchild\Grandchild.jpg
```

#### Example 4: Excluding some directories from recursion

I just found another delegate, which controls the recursive behaviour. Let's say we modify the original directory structure to include a new directory with files that we want to ignore:

```
D:\Root\
|- Child\
|  |- Grandchild\
|  |  |- Grandchild.jpg
|  |  |- Grandchild.txt
|  |- GrandchildIgnore\
|  |  |- GrandchildIgnore.txt
|  |- Child.html
|  |- Child.txt
|- Root.txt
```

To get a list of all the other files, whilst ignoring files in our new directory, we can set the `ShouldRecursePredicate`:

```
var enumeration = new FileSystemEnumerable<FileSystemInfo>(
    @"D:\Root",
    (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => entry.ToFileSystemInfo(),
    new EnumerationOptions() { RecurseSubdirectories = true })
{
    ShouldIncludePredicate = (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => !entry.IsDirectory,
    // If the directory's name ends with ignore, skip it.
    ShouldRecursePredicate = (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => !entry.ToFullPath().EndsWith("Ignore", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
};
```

Running this:

```
foreach (var item in enumeration)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.FullName);
}
```

prints:

```
D:\Root\Root.txt
D:\Root\Child\Child.html
D:\Root\Child\Child.txt
D:\Root\Child\Grandchild\Grandchild.jpg
D:\Root\Child\Grandchild\Grandchild.txt
```

excluding the directory, as we wanted.

#### Example 5: Getting the length of files

```
var enumeration = new FileSystemEnumerable<(long, string)>(
    @"D:\Root",
    (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => (entry.Length, entry.FileName.ToString()))
{
    ShouldIncludePredicate = (ref FileSystemEntry entry) => !entry.IsDirectory
};
```

Given 1 file in `D:\Root` that has 122 bytes, running this:

```
foreach (var (length, fileName) in enumeration)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {fileName} Length: {length}");
}
```

prints:

```
Name: Root.txt Length: 122
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply

I get following error though using this code?

BC30668 'FileSystemEntry' is obsolete: 'Types with embedded references are not supported in this version of your compiler.'.

Comment: @DarrenRose No problem. Which namespaces are you using, and which version of .NET Core? I'm using .NET Core 3.1, and using `System.IO` and `System.IO.Enumeration`. I'm not getting any warnings on a full rebuild.

Comment: Think it was because I was trying it in VB (my preferred language) rather than C#.  I had got imports for both of those but still that error.  Now trying it in C# project and errors gone.  Is this new API only for C# then?    And I am using 3.1 as well

Comment: got it working in c# - but I notice size (length) is not available using this method, so I can't use it to calculate sizes

Still interesting to know if this method is only for C# and not VB then

Comment: @DarrenRose I'm not 100% sure. It looks to me like it's built around use of types such as `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>`, which are both `ref struct`s. `ref struct` is a C# feature since version 7.2.

Comment: @DarrenRose You can get the `Length`. It's available on `FileSystemEntry`. You could return the length with `entry.Length`.

Comment: sounds like it is just C# then - handy to know.    I was trying to loop through them and get the length, but in the loop "foreach (var item in enumerator)" then item.length is not available? can you add to your example above how to return total length (size) of all files and folders in a given path please

Comment: @DarrenRose Just added an example for you. Edit: Totalling them is just a case of keeping a running sum in the loop, so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: @JohnH Excellent examples and well explained, thanks.

Strictly speaking, I don't think that the variables are enumerators, rather enumerations.

Comment: @doterik I'm glad you found it useful, and you're correct with your observation. I've made an edit to correct the variable names.